# Touchdowns On The Season

Tags: prepositions, slang, terminology

I have a question about the usage of the preposition "*on*" [here](http://www.baltimoresun.com/sports/ravens/bs-sp-ravens-torrey-smith-1110-20141109-story.html):

> His six touchdowns ***on*** the season lead the team and Smith's 446 yards receiving are second most on the Ravens.

I cannot find a dictionary definition that would fit this usage of "*on*".  Could this usage be  sports jargon?  Would using "*for*" be better for laymen?

Answer (score 6):

This is a **very** common construction in American sports talk.  I rarely hear it outside that realm, so yes - sports jargon.  It means "during," and is used **only** with "season" or "year."  *Shooting sixty percent **on** the season*.   *Averaging two and a half hits per game **on** the year*

For other time periods (career, playoffs, tournament, post-season, game, half, etc) *during, in,* or *for* are used.   *"Four touchdowns **in** the post-season"* or *"four touchdowns **for** the game."*  *"He was injured 8 times **during** his career."*  )

Comment: Quite true. [Examples abound](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22on+the+season%22&tbm=nws&start=10).

Answer (score 3):

I would say it is [***on***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/on) sense 6:

> 6) at or during the time of   ⇒ "on entering, on the first day"

I think this is a pretty standard usage (AmE).

Comment: BrE would have said 'for', even in sports commentary.

Comment: AmE says "for" as well, though "on" is not at all uncommon.